# How can I iterate over an object that I don't know it's keys?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, iteration

I get something like this from the server:

```
{
  "2021-10-13": {
    "1. open": "141.2350",
    "2. high": "141.4000",
    "3. low": "139.2000",
    "4. close": "140.9100",
    "5. volume": "78762721"
  },
  "2021-10-12": {
    "1. open": "143.2300",
    "2. high": "143.2500",
    "3. low": "141.0401",
    "4. close": "141.5100",
    "5. volume": "73035859"
  },
  "2021-10-11": {
    "1. open": "142.2700",
    "2. high": "144.8100",
    "3. low": "141.8100",
    "4. close": "142.8100",
    "5. volume": "64452219"
  }
}
```

The `key` values may vary for different requests. How can I iterate over an object with unknown keys?

For example I want to write the second and third nested objects(stocks) inside the database but I don't know how should I specify them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: `for( key in obj) { }` for...in loop is your friend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: although, what do you mean you know you want the second and third nested items? object keys aren't going to be in an reliable order

Comment: @DanOswalt: Yes, I am looking for a more accurate way to specify what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach for parsing the data you're receiving and sorting it by newest date first:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-WzouSyzrNsvBsvyXzVy1Dd8qczonV7KK+SPXLJ3y-dPm8JqEr5Ry7UIBZAUBQRAi7ABCTq9SPCwmyiQhNMBNgMvC+hmGY-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-Y6Z0YaLCRmAT6NggA)

```ts
const rawSummaryKeys = ['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5. volume'] as const;
type RawSummaryKey = typeof rawSummaryKeys[number];

const parsedSummaryKeys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'] as const;
type ParsedSummaryKey = typeof parsedSummaryKeys[number];

const rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping: Record<RawSummaryKey, ParsedSummaryKey> = {
  '1. open': 'open',
  '2. high': 'high',
  '3. low': 'low',
  '4. close': 'close',
  '5. volume': 'volume',
};

/** Values are parsable as numbers */
type RawSummary = Record<RawSummaryKey, string>;

/** Keys are dates in format: YYYY-MM-DD */
type DailyRawSummaries = Record<string, RawSummary>;

type ParsedSummary = Record<ParsedSummaryKey, number>;

function parseRawSummary (summary: RawSummary): ParsedSummary {
  const parsed = {} as ParsedSummary;
  for (const key of rawSummaryKeys) {
    // If the "volume" number ever exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    // then you can switch to using BigInts
    parsed[rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping[key]] = Number(summary[key]);
  }
  return parsed;
}

type DailySummaryEntrry = [date: string, summary: ParsedSummary];

function parseDailySummaries (summaries: DailyRawSummaries): DailySummaryEntrry[] {
  const entries: DailySummaryEntrry[] = [];

  for (const date in summaries) {
    const rawSummary = summaries[date];
    if (!rawSummary) continue;
    entries.push([date, parseRawSummary(rawSummary)]);
  }

  return entries.sort().reverse(); // sort by newest date first
}

function main () {
  const json = `{"2021-10-13":{"1. open":"141.2350","2. high":"141.4000","3. low":"139.2000","4. close":"140.9100","5. volume":"78762721"},"2021-10-12":{"1. open":"143.2300","2. high":"143.2500","3. low":"141.0401","4. close":"141.5100","5. volume":"73035859"},"2021-10-11":{"1. open":"142.2700","2. high":"144.8100","3. low":"141.8100","4. close":"142.8100","5. volume":"64452219"}}`;
  const raw: DailyRawSummaries = JSON.parse(json);

  const parsed = parseDailySummaries(raw);

  for (const [date, summary] of parsed) {
    console.log(date, summary);
  }
}

main();
```

Transpiled JS from TS playground:

```js
const rawSummaryKeys = ['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5. volume'];
const parsedSummaryKeys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'];
const rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping = {
    '1. open': 'open',
    '2. high': 'high',
    '3. low': 'low',
    '4. close': 'close',
    '5. volume': 'volume',
};
function parseRawSummary(summary) {
    const parsed = {};
    for (const key of rawSummaryKeys) {
        // If the "volume" number ever exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        // then you can switch to using BigInts
        parsed[rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping[key]] = Number(summary[key]);
    }
    return parsed;
}
function parseDailySummaries(summaries) {
    const entries = [];
    for (const date in summaries) {
        const rawSummary = summaries[date];
        if (!rawSummary)
            continue;
        entries.push([date, parseRawSummary(rawSummary)]);
    }
    return entries.sort().reverse(); // sort by newest date first
}
function main() {
    const json = `{"2021-10-13":{"1. open":"141.2350","2. high":"141.4000","3. low":"139.2000","4. close":"140.9100","5. volume":"78762721"},"2021-10-12":{"1. open":"143.2300","2. high":"143.2500","3. low":"141.0401","4. close":"141.5100","5. volume":"73035859"},"2021-10-11":{"1. open":"142.2700","2. high":"144.8100","3. low":"141.8100","4. close":"142.8100","5. volume":"64452219"}}`;
    const raw = JSON.parse(json);
    const parsed = parseDailySummaries(raw);
    for (const [date, summary] of parsed) {
        console.log(date, summary);
    }
}
main();
```

Comment: What does `[number]` mean in `type RawSummaryKey = typeof rawSummaryKeys[number];` statement?

Comment: @WDR It is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) on the tuple: so it represents a union of each of the types within. You can see a representation of that type when you hover over the type name in an environment with IntelliSense (like the playground).

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps. May you also say what does the `Number` function do? here:  `Number(summary[key]);`

Comment: @WDR What do you think it does?

Comment: It seems it's just a type caster but I am not sure.

Comment: @WDR [You got it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: In your code, when I print the `entries` the result is like `[
  [
    "2022-03-11",      
    {
      open: "158.9300",
      high: "159.2800",
      low: "154.5000", 
      close: "154.7300",
      volume: "96970102"
    }
  ],
  [
    "2022-03-10",
    {
      open: "160.2000",
      high: "160.3900",
      low: "155.9800",
      close: "158.5200",
      volume: "105342033"
    }
  ],
]` That is an array of arrays of object.

Comment: How can I convert it to object of objects like `{
    "2022-03-11" :     
    {
      open: "158.9300",
      high: "159.2800",
      low: "154.5000", 
      close: "154.7300",
      volume: "96970102"
    }
  ,
    "2022-03-10" :
    {
      open: "160.2000",
      high: "160.3900",
      low: "155.9800",
      close: "158.5200",
      volume: "105342033"
    }
  }`

Comment: @WDR Objects are not ordered in JS/TS. which is why I provided an order-sensitive, iterable structure (`entries`) in the answer.

Comment: That's right, but how should I write them into the MongoDB? Isn't it better to convert them to an object like my previous comment, then write it to DataBase?

Comment: Actually I want to add another key to this result as the name of the stock and after that, it becomes something like this `[
  [
    "AAPL",
    [
      [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
      [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ],
    ],
]` That I don't know if is it good idea to save them like this? It seems a redundency of `[` array to array `]`

Comment: And if I want to add another stock it becomes like:  `[
    "MSFT",
    [
      [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
      [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ],
    ],
],
  [
    "AAPL",
    [
      [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
      [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ],
    ],
]`  Is it efficient to save it like this into a MongoDB database?

Comment: @WDR Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow, and check out the help center section about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Each question should focus on a single problem. I have answered the question that you asked, and you are free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have another question (e.g. about how to use data structures in your program).

Comment: I tried to do some modification and created a new question here. I appreciate your help also there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462277/how-can-i-store-my-data-into-the-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```js
type Keys = {
  "1. open": string;
  "2. high": string;
  "3. low": string;
  "4. close": string;
  "5. volume": string;
}
type B = {[Prop in keyof Keys]: Keys[Prop]}
type A = { [key: string]: B}
const result: A = {
  "2021-10-13": {
    "1. open": "141.2350",
    "2. high": "141.4000",
    "3. low": "139.2000",
    "4. close": "140.9100",
    "5. volume": "78762721"
  },
  "2021-10-12": {
    "1. open": "143.2300",
    "2. high": "143.2500",
    "3. low": "141.0401",
    "4. close": "141.5100",
    "5. volume": "73035859"
  },
  "2021-10-11": {
    "1. open": "142.2700",
    "2. high": "144.8100",
    "3. low": "141.8100",
    "4. close": "142.8100",
    "5. volume": "64452219"
  }
};
```

Comment: I can not understand how this statement works? `type A = { [key: string]: B};`

Comment: @WDR It is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and represents an object that has the type `B` at every property name that is a `string`. Another way to write that type using a [utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) would be `Record<string, B>`.