# How can I store my data into the MongoDB?

Tags: json, database, typescript, mongodb, store

I am trying to download stock data using Alpha Vantage API. I send a request and after some work on responded data I have an array like below:

```
[
  {
    id: "MSFT",
    stockData: [
      { date: "1634601600", summary: [Object] },
      { date: "1634688000", summary: [Object] }        ]
  }
]
```

And `[Object]` is something like:

```
  {
    date: "1646956800",
    summary: { open: 287.96, high: 289.51, low: 279.43, close: 280.07, volume: 27209330 }
  }
```

But I don't know how can I save it into the MongoDB? I could save a simpler structure and I knew I must create a class with the same property names as the response JSON, then instantiate the class and assign the properties of the response value to the properties of the class instance then save it to the database.

But now I am a little confused and don't know how properly deal with this. Also what if I have an array with more nested values of different size like below:

```
   [
      {
        id: "AAPL",
        stockData: [
          { date: 1634601600, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634688000, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634774400, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634860800, summary: [Object] }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "MSFT",
        stockData: [
          { date: 1634601600, summary: [Object] },
          { date: 1634688000, summary: [Object] }
        ]
      }
  ]
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what answer you're looking for, but your schema should serve your common data access patterns as they will take the biggest toll on your db. I would start by mapping out exactly what reads/writes you expect to be doing, it will then be easier to think of the "right" solution.

Comment: I think a reasonable schema is to store each summary instance as a flattened collection (all keys in each `summary` object along with `date` and `id` for each entry). This would be like a traditional row entry in a table and will allow you to query by a combination of any of those fields to get the data you want.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert: I wanna write the whole data I read from Alpha Vantage API that is something similar to the last array in my question. Then I want to read one of the `stockData`s I stored into the database by calling their name/id. For examle reading this array `[{ date: 1634601600, summary: [Object] }, { date: 1634688000, summary: [Object] }]` by sending a query for the `MSFT` id.

Comment: @jsejcksn, As I use Deno I know Mongoose doesn't work with it. So I don't know any alternative library/middleware helping to work with schemas in Deno.